# Device not detected by Xcode4 but Organizer

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, organizer

I would know is there is a reason to a non-detection of any device by Xcode but Organizer yes. This fail happen only when I create a new project under Xcode4...
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a developer certificate in XCode to work with the device? If you don't, or if you are targeting a version of iOS higher than the one on your device, XCode may not show it as an option to deploy your application. A workaround for not having a developer certificate from Apple is jailbreaking your device.

Comment: I'm targeted iOS 3.0, devices work well on previous projects and there are not jailbraked... Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Open the Organizer of XCode (top right button), then click on the device, and check that your developer certificate is OK. There is a bug on XCode 4 that restores expired certificates. This may or may not be your case, but doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: That was not that too, in fact I've found my problem and you was right. I don't know why but I was targeting 3.0 in the project configuration well but not in the target. I clicked and clicked on deployment target, while thinkin it changing too in the target case. I'm so retarded. Thx anyway