# iPad with iOS 5.1 not detected - Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: ipad, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I have just updated my xcode to 4.3.1. I added a snapshot below:

[image]

And my iPad with iOS 5.1:

[image]

But my xcode is not detecting iPad. :( Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you looking in the Organizer window to see if it can detect the iPad there ?

It is the best way to know where the problem comes from ... and check that your developer certificate is ok.

If it is not detected by XCode but you see it in Organizer go check this link : 
[XCode Organizer Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792455/device-not-detected-by-xcode4-but-organizer)

Last thing, you can forget everything if your iPad is jailbreaked.